# Не работает сохранение данных из формы

Tags: yii2

Приветствую. Делаю редактирование профиля пользователя, не работает сохранение. Опытным путем выяснил, что не работает считывание полей формы в свойства модели (`$model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())`). Прошу помочь выяснить почему. Итак, привожу код:

(все `use` и `namespace` не привожу - они на месте, оставляю только суть)

```
UserController.php (контроллер)

  public function actionProfile()
  {
    $model = new ProfileForm(); // создаем объект модели с формой ProfileForm

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) { // вот тут условие проходит, но функция не срабатывает - $model не содержит полей из формы

      if ($user = $model->update()) {

        return $this->redirect('/user/profile');
      }
    }

    return $this->render('profile', [
      'model' => $model
    ]);
  }
```

ProfileForm.php (модель формы)

```
class ProfileForm extends Model
{
  public $username;
  public $email;
  public $firstname;
  public $middlename;
  public $lastname;

  public function update()
  {
    $user = \Yii::$app->user->identity;

    $user->country = $this->username;
    $user->country = $this->email;
    $user->firstname = $this->firstname;
    $user->middlename = $this->middlename;
    $user->lastname = $this->lastname;

    return $user->save() ? $user : null;
  }
}
```

profile.php (view формы профиля)

```
$user = \Yii::$app->user->identity;

<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'form-signup']); ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'username')->label('Имя пользователя')->textInput(['value' => $user->username, 'readonly' => true]) ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'email')->label('Ваш e-mail')->textInput(['value'=>$user->email, 'readonly' => true]) ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'firstname')->label('Имя')->textInput(['value'=>$user->firstname]) ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'middlename')->label('Отчество')->textInput(['value'=>$user->middlename]) ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'lastname')->label('Фамилия')->textInput(['value'=>$user->lastname]) ?>

<?= Html::submitButton('Сохранить', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => 'signup-button']) ?>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Объект `\Yii:$app->user->identity` реализуется в модели `Users`. Тут ничего интересного (привожу на всякий случай):

```
<?php

namespace frontend\models;

use yii\db\ActiveRecord;
use yii\web\IdentityInterface;

class Users extends ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface
{

  public static function tableName() {
    return 'users';
  }

  public function setPassword($password) {
    $this->password_hash = md5($password);
  }

  public function validatePassword($password) {
    return $this->password_hash === md5($password);
  }

  public static function findIdentity($id) {
    return self::findOne($id);
  }

  public function getId() {
    return $this->id;
  }

  public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null) {
  }

  public function getAuthKey() {
  }

  public function validateAuthKey($authKey) {
  }
}
```

Итак, опытным путем выяснил, что проблема в контролере (в самом начале):

```
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
```

условие срабатывает. Но насколько я понимаю, функция `$model = load($post_data)` должна считать элементы массива `$post_data` и заполнить их в массиве `$model` при условии что у обоих элементов одинаковые индексы.

То есть было:

```
['username' => 'тут старые данные из базы'],
['email' => 'тут старые данные из базы'],
['firstname' => 'тут старые данные из базы'],
['middlename' => 'тут старые данные из базы'],
['lastname' => 'тут старые данные из базы'],

Yii::$app->request->post() [
    ['username' => 'тут новые данные из формы'],
    ['email' => 'тут новые данные из формы'],
    ['firstname' => 'тут новые данные из формы'],
    ['middlename' => 'тут новые данные из формы'],
    ['lastname' => 'тут новые данные из формы'],
]
```

После `if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()))`
должно стать:

```
$model [
    ['username' => 'тут новые данные из формы'],
    ['email' => 'тут новые данные из формы'],
    ['firstname' => 'тут новые данные из формы'],
    ['middlename' => 'тут новые данные из формы'],
    ['lastname' => 'тут новые данные из формы'],
]
```

Но данные `$model` не обновляются. Я долго искал примеры использования функции `load()`, и как мне кажется, понял правильно как она работает. Но почему тогда не происходит сохранения? При создании нового пользователя я делал так же и все работало, а при редактировании не работает. Прошу помочь. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Потому что все поля вашей модели по умолчанию не безопасные и метод `load()` не срабатывает.

В `ProfileForm` необходимо добавить метод `rulse()`, хотя бы просто с указанием на то что вы доверяете вашим атрибутам:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['username', 'email', 'firstname', 'middlename', 'lastname'], 'safe']
    ];
}
```

Вы можете использовать любой другой валидатор, который так же будет указывать на то что атрибут безопасен (то есть проходит проверку валидатором).

P.S. Проверка `if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()))` будет равна `if(!empty($_POST))` или `if(isset($_POST['ModelName']))` в зависимости от ситуации. Это что бы было понятно почему проходит проверка.